# Crosswalk Project Service not found on Samsung Galaxy S6 and S6 Edge

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

my app uses the cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.3.1, Ionic 1.0.0-rc.1 and Cordova 5.2.0.
If I start the app on the Samsung Galaxy S5 it starts properly, but on the Samsung Galaxy S6 or S6 Edge I get the message

> "Crosswalk Project Service Not Found ... requires the Crosswalk
>   Project Service to work. Please install it from the app store, then
>   restart ..."

Based on the installed size of the app, Crosswalk is embedded. Also I have set xwalkMode = "embedded" and the uses-permissions.

config.xml

```
<preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Any ideas what causes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/336

The cordova sqlite plugin in connection with the crosswalk plugin on an x86 64bit device caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not installing the wrong architecture app onto your device. The x86 build should be installed onto x86 devices and the ARM build should be installed on ARM devices.

The version codes in the two files are designed so you can submit both to the Google store and the right one will be delivered to the right device. Also, if an ARM build gets accidentally installed onto an x86 device the app will automatically prompt the user to download and install the shared Crosswalk library from the Google Play store.